# Load part of image in desired resolution android

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin

I have image saved in phone memory. I need to get some part of the entire image in desired resolution. I could possibly first downscale the entire image and then "decodeRegion" from it. Is there any way to "decodeDownScaledRegion" in one go rather than first downscaling original image and decoding region from it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could follow the document "Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently" here:

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html